# I could not cast integer values to string

Tags: java, json, hibernate, classcastexception

```
 Query query = s.createQuery("from ClientList");

 List <String> results = query.list();
 Iterator<String> it = results.iterator();
 while(it.hasNext())
 {
     Object[] row = (Object[]) it.next();

     System.out.println("ReturnValues==========" + results);

     Map<String, String> jsonObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
     jsonObject.put("Record_Id", (String) row[0]);
     jsonObject.put("Client_Code", (String)row[1]);
     jsonObject.put("Client_Description", (String)row[2]);

     returnValues.add(jsonObject);
}
```

The first column of my table contains an integer value. I'm getting this error message:

```
Exception===java.lang.ClassCastException:  cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

Comment: It would help, if you post how a row looks like. Especially, how is the data in row separated? By space, semicolon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your itetator returns a string. You **can't** cast it to an array of object.

There is a `split` method in string, it splits your string by given regex and returns a `String[]` containing the split parts.

---

Since you provided no more information on that, I'm going to assume that the data in your row is separated by spaces.

```
String row = ll.next() // I assume row = "1234 5678 Description_No_Spaces"
String[] data = row.split("\\s+");

String record_Id = data[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an iterator, you can loop through `results` with foreach loop.

```
List <String> results =query.list();
for(String result: results) {
   String[] row = /* user result.split(...)  to get attributes*/

 System.out.println("ReturnValues=========="+results);
 Map<String, String> JSonObject=new HashMap<String, String>();
 JSonObject.put("Record_Id", row[0]);
 JSonObject.put("Client_Code", row[1]);
 JSonObject.put("Client_Description",row[2]);
 ReturnValues.add(JSonObject);
```

}

Check out [String.split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
Query query = s.createQuery("from ClientList");

 List <String> results = query.list();
 Iterator<String> it = results.iterator();
     while(it.hasNext())`enter code here`
 {
     Object[] row = (Object[]) it.next();

     System.out.println("ReturnValues==========" + results);

     Map<String, String> jsonObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
     jsonObject.put("Record_Id", String.valueOf(row[0]));
     jsonObject.put("Client_Code", row[1]);
     jsonObject.put("Client_Description", row[2]);

     returnValues.add(jsonObject);
}
```

Hope this solves your problem